# C - How to free a struct array cell completely

Tags: c, struct, free

I read some other questions like this here on stack overflow, and I fixed the problem I had with my use of free();

I have a struct array of this type:

```
typedef struct _event {
char* desc;
int start;
int end;
} event;
```

But it seems I can only free the `desc`, while if I try to use the free for the two integers (start/end), it doesn't work. 
Reading the other answers in other posts, I understood that I can't free something I haven't malloc'd. The point is: I don't need to `malloc()` an integer. But on my exercise, I *really* need to erase that array block. (I don't mean the whole array, just that block).

I don't want to put much code in this post to don't bother the reader, but if you need please tell me!

At the moment I am using:

```
free(event[i].desc);
```

in a `for` loop under a certain `if` statement. 
The question is how to `free` also `event[i].start` and `event[i].end` ?

Thank you in advance, I am sorry about the dumb question, but I wanted to know if it is possible to free the entire cell instead of using a marker like '0'.

P.S. If you know a good article or tutorial about `free()` function, can you please link it to me?

Comment: But you don't allocate memory for `start` and `end`, do you? Then why should you free it? Trying to free memory you have not allocated can lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Also, the members `start` and `end` are like normal variables, you would not attempt to free a local `int` variable would you?

Comment: We need to understand what you mean by "free": do you want to reset the value of `start` and `end` or do you want to mark the space occupied by these variables as available, because you don't need it anymore ?

Comment: Yes @JoachimPileborg that's exactly the problem. The thing is: I do this operation, and if there are elements that don't respect a condition, they must be removed. 
Therefore, the only thing I can do to get rid of them is shift them at the end and then `realloc()` the array? I never did that, but I could try to learn
- Coconop, I need to remove them completely from my array

Comment: Perhaps the confusion comes from the sloppy way that people talk about "freeing a pointer". That's not accurate. You never "free the pointer". Instead, you free some *memory*, and you refer to that memory by means of some pointer.

Comment: "I *really* need to erase that array block." You *really* can't. Imagine array of integers. You cannot simply "remove" one element in the middle. You need to think on two separate levels. One is construction and deconstruction of `_event` (this is where `free(desc)` is important). The second is how you organize and manage your events - this is your array of `_event`s, but it doesn't matter what type it is, you cannot simply remove an element from `T array[SIZE]`. You combined, mixed and confused the two levels of abstraction.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, so what I can do is simply 'shift' at the end the elements of the struct array that I don't need and 'reset' them.

Comment: No `malloc`, no `free`. `malloc` allocates memory in `heap section`, while `free` deallocate memory in `heap section`. Variable allocated in `stack section` will be `freed` auto. You can `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation` and `http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html`for help.

Comment: @zybjtu thank you for your links! I am going to read them right now, I just ended my exercise and fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allocated event as a block, e.g.

```
event * p = (event *) malloc(sizeof(event);
p->desc = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE); // presume SIZE defined earlier
```

then, you could free in reverse sequence as below:

```
free(p->desc);
free(p); // will deallocate the entire block
```

Hope this is what you meant to know.

Comment: Hello, I allocated firstly the bloc in this way: `event* eventi = (event*) malloc(sizeof(event)*n);`
Then, I allocated the cell in the for loop for each event: `eventi[i] = *(event*) malloc(sizeof(event));`
Lastly, I allocated the space for the string `eventi[i].desc = (char*) malloc(sizeof(value));` (Where value is a char[101]). But I get an error of type (passing type event to void* ). Sorry for the bad formatting of my post! I am new here and I don't know how to start a new paragraph in these answers

Comment: @Roberto event* eventi = (event*) malloc(sizeof(event)*n); will allocate n events. Then you need do in a for loop from 0 to n-1, allocate for eventi[i]->desc, and finally upon done, deallocate as free(eventi), that's all.

Comment: Thank you @Debasish. Sorry if my question was a bit dumb, but I am trying to really understand how a free() function works, and this thread helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that you cannot `free` just a part of your structure:
In your case you have a pointer on `char` and 2 `int`.

The `char*` can store an address you get via `malloc`: this can be freed. But the 2 `int` cannot.
If for some reason they became irrelevant and you really need to get rid of these variables, then you probably defined your structure the wrong way: you might want to split it.

An other solution could be to reset these fields with a default value (like `0` or `-1` or whatever you define), and free the  `char *` as @Debasish Jana explained.

Comment: Thank you Coconop, you where really helpful! I fixed it and my exercise is now solved!